# Active strings in WinEdt 8

Tags: winedt

I use WinEdt build 20131031  (v. 8.1) - 64-bit on a Windows 7 (64 bit) machine. My active strings are not working. I tried a lot, e.g., "Load Script" in the Options Interface (under Delimiters, Active Strings, Abbreviations... -> Active Strings).

For example, I would like to have the typical `\ref{}` active string (such that the labels given in the main file pop-up after typing in `\ref{}`). It does not work (by contrast to WinEdt 5 or so). Now it becomes really weird: I have created my own active strings and put them into a file called `myActiveStrings.ini` which is located in `%b\ConfigEx\`. In `ActiveStrings.ini` (i.e., the active strings file that comes with WinEdt) I inserted `%INCLUDE="ConfigEx\myActiveStrings.ini"`. Now, my OWN active strings work, but not the active strings in `ActiveStrings.ini`!

Help...! ;-)

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Indeed, it was my own ini-file which made WinEdt's active strings no more working. I used the following code in `myActiveStrings.ini`:

```
// ===============================================================================
// -*- DATA:INI:EDT -*-
//
// My WinEdt Active Strings
//
// ===============================================================================

[BUILD]

REQUIRES=20131017

// ===============================================================================

[ACTIVE_STRINGS]

<Body>

[END]
```

So, I guess by `[END]` I apparently made WinEdt to think that there are no more active strings and so it simply skipped the proprietary ones... ;-) After deleting

```
[BUILD]

REQUIRES=20131017

// ===============================================================================

[ACTIVE_STRINGS]
```

and

```
[END]
```

from the code, all things work perfect.

Comment: This works, but the right way to go in WinEdt is the one in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add your own active strings, you have to add the line

```
%INCLUDE="ConfigEx\myActiveStrings.ini"
```

in the file `ActiveStrings.ini` just before the line

```
[END]
```

as you did, but the structure of `myActiveStrings.ini` has to be the following one:

```
// ===============================================================================
// -*- DATA:INI:EDT -*-
//
// My WinEdt Active Strings
//
// ===============================================================================

[BUILD]

REQUIRES=20131017

// ===============================================================================

[ACTIVE_STRINGS*]

<your own code>

// ===============================================================================
```

Note the asterisk in `[ACTIVE_STRINGS*]` and the absence of `[END]`.